# Understanding why Java selection rank returns max() as final result

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working out a solution to the following question:

> Describe an algorithm to find the smallest one million numbers in one
>   billion numbers. Assume that the computer memory can hold all one
>   billion numbers.

The book gives the a selection rank solution but I am having a hard time understanding a few parts of it:

```
public static int partition(int[] array, int left, int right, int pivot) {
    while (true) {
        while (left <= right && array[left] <= pivot) {
            left++;
        }

        while (left <= right && array[right] > pivot) {
            right--;
        }

        if (left > right) {
            return left - 1;
        } 
        swap(array, left, right);
    }
}

public static int rank(int[] array, int left, int right, int rank) {
    int pivot = array[randomIntInRange(left, right)];
    int leftEnd = partition(array, left, right, pivot); // returns end of left partition
    int leftSize = leftEnd - left + 1;
    if (leftSize == rank + 1) {
        return max(array, left, leftEnd);
    } else if (rank < leftSize) {
        return rank(array, left, leftEnd, rank);
    } else {
        return rank(array, leftEnd + 1, right, rank - leftSize);
    }
}
```

I understand most of it, but I do no understand the following two lines above:

```
if (leftSize == rank + 1) {
            return max(array, left, leftEnd);
```

**1.** Why are we returning the max of the three variables?

**2.** Shouldn't we just be returning `array[left:leftEnd]` or something of that nature?

Comment: It would be good to explain or show the code for max().

Comment: It wasn't given. I thought it was a built-in in Java?

Comment: It's not. My guess it it's returning the max in the segment of the array between left and leftEnd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations on trying to learn something by carefully studying a book. It's a key skill that seems to be getting rarer.

It makes general sense if the definition of the return value of `rank` is "there exist exactly a million numbers less than or equal to `rank`."  The definition of `max` would be something like:

```
int t = array[left];
for (int i = left + 1; i <= leftEnd; i++) 
  t = Math.max(t, array[i]);
return t;
```

Returning the max value is beyond the problem statement and kind of weird. It would be better and simpler just to partition the elements so that the max million are at the top: `array[0] through array[999999]`.  Then find the max only if that's actually needed

Note that because `rank` is tail recursive, there's a simple iterative version of the same code that I think would be clearer.

I'm also not convinced this code is correct.  `leftSize == rank` in the check makes more sense than `leftSize == rank + 1`. But without more definitions and calling code, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks, could you point to the iterative version of the same code?

Comment: @ApathyBear Ok, see addition.

Answer (score 0):

The same rank function is used in *Cracking the Coding Interview 6th Edition p. 569* (aside from the line: `if (leftSize == rank + 1) {` is modified to `rank - 1`).

The max function is provided, listed below:

```
/* Get largest element in array between left and right indices */
int max(int[] array, int left, int right)
{
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = left; i <= right; i++) 
    {
        max = Math.max(array[i], max);
    }
    return max;
}
```

As for an explanation: `rank(array, rank)` returns the element which would be at the ith position of the sorted array.

`leftEnd` is the position of the pivot. If there are `rank - 1` elements before the pivot element, then there are `rank` elements including said pivot.

I believe that the pivot will always be the max element, therefore the call to `max(array, left, leftEnd);` can be replaced with `return pivot;`